# I have a symbol lookup error

Tags: makefile, linker

I have a job on program porting, so I made a Makefile.am and configure.ac.

I'm not pretty sure that these are fine, because I have no person to ask about it, so only thing I could do was finding GNU Make Manual, watching previous written documents and searching Google.

All what I did worked, I guess, because building was finished without any error. Now I can see the symbol in the shared library and also the executable is linking the library, which is checked by the objdump command.

However, When I execute the executable, the symbol lookup error occurs.

> symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libtest.so.0 : undefined symbol:
>   _ZNK8CryptoPP22BufferedTransformation14AnyRetrievableEv

I did everything in the google, but I can't figure it out.

I check the header, linking order, etc.

What should I do to solve it?

Comment: Are you trying to port only the program, or the program and the build system? Do you know how to build the program *without* Make?

Comment: I am trying to port only programs that are libraries and a executable. No, I do not know how to build the program without Make program on the board. I just heard that I must use Automake program for construction on it.

Comment: I do not know automake very well, but my impression is that it is not smart enough to be used this way, without understanding of the underlying process.

Comment: Yes, I agree with it.. It can not be a smart way because I have no prior knowledge of this.
I just heard that I have to use automake to build a program. That's the reason I learnt and used this way..

What is more smarter way to solve it, you think?

Comment: I think the best way is to talk to the person who created the program and the build system. The second best way is to obtain a working version on the old platform, so that you can do experiments. Third best is to examine the source code and create a build system from zero, with the help of an expert coder. Fourth best is third best without help.

Comment: Um, It is not the answer I've wanted, but thanks for your help very much.

Actually, I've failed my senior's mission and he did it by his own. I'm very sad.
So, I'm gonna compare my one with his one. I hope I could find where I did the fault.

Thank you very much. If I find the point causing this error, I'll post it.